# Encrypt file with .asc extension from Nautilus

Tags: gnupg

Is it possible to encrypt file with .asc extension directly from Nautilus?

I tried with Seahorse add on but its always encrypting with gpg extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool](http://www.nautilus-actions.org/) and create an action to do this.
Find the application in [Software Centre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/nautilus-actions/)

From **Gnome Terminal** type:

```bash
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
nautilus -q
nautilus-actions-config-tool
```

[image: Main Window]

Then add you action like this:

[image: Action Window]

path = /usr/bin/pgp
parameter = --recipient "" --armor --encrypt %f

Now when you right click on file, you'll see this
[image: Context Menu]

---

Actual Result (even if not GUI, because I don't have `nautilus-actions-config-tool` installed) :

[image: gpg asc]

Comment: Could you please expand, answers containing link-only solution aren't welcome on AskUbuntu in case of the website it's poiting to gets offline. In this case, you could add steps from the "nice guide" in your answer and provide the name of the package "nautilus-actions configuration tool".

Comment: Hi @MrVaykadji, I'll try to correct the answer

Comment: @DiegoVicentini : Does it give me the option to set a desired extension (.asc) to my file?

Comment: Yes, it does ;) see the image I added.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file .asc with GPG on older versions. Now, you'll have to rename the extension. So, create `file.pgp`, and `mv file.pgp file.asc` to rename it.

That should be it.

In [here](http://www.benmccann.com/blog/creating-asc-signature-files-with-gpg/), it's also said that you can do that :

1) First make sure you don’t have a key already:

```
gpg --list-keys
```

2) If you didn’t and need to create a key then run:

```
gpg --gen-key
```

It might hang for awhile while generating enough random entropy. Run `ls -R /` to speed things up.

3) And upload it to a public key server:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu --send-keys <keyid>
```

4) Now list the keys again to get the keyid:

```
gpg --list-keys
```

The keyid is the half after the `/` in:

> pub   XXXX/XXXXXXXX 2011-12-05

5) Then generate your key:

```
gpg -ab <filename>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking for a way to encrypt a file . Final output should be a .asc file . I should be able to do this from Nautilus not commandline

Comment: And you already use `seahorse-nautilus` but you don't want .gpg ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct.